# Using multicolumn and multirow together with spreadtab

Tags: tables, calculations, multirow, multicolumn

I tried this piece down

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[inner=0.75in,outer=0.65in,top=0.75in,bottom=0.65in]{geometry}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{spreadtab}
\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!htb]
\centering
\caption{Sample} \vspace{3pt}
\begin{spreadtab}{{tabular}{|c|l|l|c|c|c|c|c|c|}}
\hline
@\multirow{2}{*}{Sl No.} & 
@\multicolumn{2}{|c}{\multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{something}}} & 
@\multicolumn{4}{|c}{\textbf{s}} & 
@\textbf{a~/~b} & 
@\multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Total}} \\ \cline{3-6}
&  &  & @\textbf{x} & @\textbf{y} & @\textbf{z} & @\textbf{m} & 
@\textbf{/~c} & \\ \hline
@\multirow{2}{*}{1} & @1 \& & @x & & & & 1 & & 
\STcopy{v}{d3+e4+f4+g4+h4}\\ \cline{1-1} \cline{3-9}
& @Safety & @\textbf{Sub Total} & {\fontseries{b}\selectfont}\Stcopy{>}{d3}    &
\textbf{:={}} & \textbf{:={}} & \textbf{:={}} & \textbf{: ={}} & \textbf{:={}} 
\\ \hline

\end{spreadtab}
\label{tab:tofisa}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Is there any alternate method to do the same?

Can \multicolumn and \multirow be used as above with spreadtab???

Comment: What are those @s supposed to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\multicolumn` and `\multirow` can certainly be used in such a table.  I am not sure what your table is trying to achieve/display but here is a slightly cut-down version:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[inner=0.75in,outer=0.65in,top=0.75in,bottom=0.65in]{geometry}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{spreadtab}
\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
  \centering
  \caption{Sample} \vspace{3pt}
  \begin{spreadtab}{{tabular}{|c|l|l|c|c|c|c|c|c|}}
    \hline
    @\multirow{2}{*}{Sl No.} &
    @\multicolumn{2}{c}{\multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{something}}} &
    @\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\textbf{s}} & @\textbf{a~/~b} &
    @\multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Total}} \\
    \cline{4-7}
    & @\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{} & @\textbf{x} & @\textbf{y} & @\textbf{z}
    & @\textbf{m} & @\textbf{/~c} & \\ 
    \hline
    @\multirow{2}{*}{1} & @1 \& & @x &2 &3 &2 & 1 & 3&
    \STcopy{v}{d3+e3+f3+g3}
    \\
    \cline{3-9}
    & @Safety & @\textbf{Sub Total} & 3 & 3 & 9 & 7 &3 & \\ \hline
    @\multirow{2}{*}{2} & @2 \& & @x &6 &3 &5 & 1 & 3&
    \\
    \cline{3-9}
    & @Safety & @\textbf{Sub Total} & 2 & 10 & 1 & 7 &3 & \\ \hline
  \end{spreadtab}
  \label{tab:tofisa}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

When using `\multirow` make sure that there are corresponding empty cells in the rows below.

Your original code contains at least one syntax error `\Stcopy` should be `\STcopy`.  Also beware of `:=` and its special syntax etc.  I think these entries were causing the main problems.

Comment: Though I meant something the question was answered.