# Table with multirow and multicolumn

Tags: tables, multicol, multirow

I want to create a table with `\multirow` and `\multicolumn` in LaTeX.

I tried some post [1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/131668/using-multicolumn-and-multirow-together-with-spreadtab), [2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/167366/combining-multirow-and-multicolumn), [3](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/130424/formatting-of-tables-in-latex-using-multirow-and-multicolumn-together) to create my table but because I wasn't able to create my table.

Please help me with LaTeX code for the table given below.

[image]

I wrote this code so far:

```
\begin{tabular}{ |p{5cm}|p{4cm}|p{3cm}|p{3cm}| } 
\hline 
\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\textbf{Crop field location info}} \\ 
\hline 
\textbf{District name} & \textbf{Tehsil name} & \textbf{UC name} 
  & \textbf{UC \#}\\ & & &\\ 
\hline  
\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\textbf{Farmer's info}} \\ 
\hline 
\textbf{Farmer name} & \textbf{Farmer contact \#}
  & \multicolumn{2}{ |c| }{\textbf{Farmer's land holding (acres)}} \\ 
& & \multicolumn{2}{ |c| }{} \\ 
\hline 
\textbf{Item} & \textbf{Unit} & \textbf{Rate/Unit} & \textbf{Total Cost}\\
\hline 
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: Please tell us what you've tried so far, LaTeX-wise. Please also tell us more about the document class, the font, the font size, and the width and height of the text block that are in use in your document.

Comment: In your tabular there is no multirow, just multicolumn

Comment: @Mico I wrote this code so far;  \begin{tabular}{ |p{5cm}|p{4cm}|p{3cm}|p{3cm}|  }
 \hline
 \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\textbf{Crop field location info}} \\
 \hline
 \textbf{District name} & \textbf{Tehsil name} & \textbf{UC name} & \textbf{UC \#}\\
  & & &\\
 \hline
 \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\textbf{Farmer's info}} \\
 \hline
 \textbf{Farmer name} & \textbf{Farmer contact \#} & \multicolumn{2}{ |c| }{\textbf{Farmer's land holding (acres)}} \\
  & & \multicolumn{2}{ |c| }{} \\
 \hline
 \textbf{Item} & \textbf{Unit} & \textbf{Rate/Unit} & \textbf{Total Cost}\\
 \hline
\end{tabular}

Comment: But I don't know that what to do for column separtion for Unit -- Quantity and Rate/Unit -- All Cost.

Comment: I have edited you code in the comment into the question.  It is better to add code there because it is easier to preserve linebreaks etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your effort for prepare MWE is to minimal :_), so I down wrote from your image only beginning of table. For your table you don't need multirow cells. An simple solution is as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}

%just for show only a table
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tabular}
    \setlength\PreviewBorder{1em}


    \begin{document}
    \sffamily
    \small
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\begin{tabular}{|p{0.4\textwidth}   % determine column width to your wish
                |p{0.1\textwidth}
                |p{0.15\textwidth}
                |p{0.15\textwidth}
                |p{0.20\textwidth}|
                }
    \hline
\multicolumn{5}{|c|}{Crop field location info}\\
    \hline
District name & 
    \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Tehsil name} 
                    & UC name   & UC \#                     \\[2em]
    \hline
\multicolumn{5}{|c|}{Farmer's info}                         \\
    \hline
Farmer name &
    \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Farmer contract \#} 
                    & 
    \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Farmer's Land holdings (acres)}    \\[2em]
    \hline
Item        & Unit  & Quality   & Rate/Unit & All cost      \\
    \hline
% repeat regarding to your table contents ...   
\multicolumn{1}{|c}{}
            &
    \multicolumn{4}{ c|}{Land preparation cost}             \\
    \hline
Ploughing \& planking (Bullocks)       
            & Rs./Hr  &         &           &               \\
    \hline
etc         &         &         &           &               \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `\multicol` package for this task. Here I have an example of the first few rows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ |p{5cm}|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|p{3cm}|p{3cm}| } 
\hline 
\multicolumn{5}{|c|}{\textbf{Crop field location info}} \\ 
\hline 
\textbf{District name} & \multicolumn{2}{ |c| }{\textbf{Tehsil name}} 
    & \textbf{UC name} & \textbf{UC \#}\\ 
& \multicolumn{2}{ |c| }{} & &\\ 
\hline 
\multicolumn{5}{|c|}{\textbf{Farmer's info}} \\
\hline 
\textbf{Farmer name} & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textbf{Farmer contact \#}} 
    & \multicolumn{2}{ |c| }{\textbf{Farmer's land holding (acres)}} \\
& \multicolumn{2}{ |c| }{} & \multicolumn{2}{ |c| }{} \\ 
\hline 
\textbf{Item} & \textbf{Unit} & \textbf{Quantity} & \textbf{Rate/Unit} & \textbf{Total Cost}\\ 
\hline 
& \multicolumn{4}{ c| }{\textbf{Land preparation cost}} \\
\hline
Ploughing \& planking (Bullocks) & Rs./hr & & & \\
\hline
Leveling (Bullocks) & Rs./hr & & & \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

More information on the correct usage can be found at [latex_tables](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables)

Comment: there is no need to `multicol` package

Comment: @lenxn I wrote the below code so far but I don't know what to do for column division for below the 'Farmer contact #' and 'Farmer's Land holding (coloumns)'. The code is in the next comment.

Comment: \begin{tabular}{ |p{5cm}|p{4cm}|p{3cm}|p{3cm}|  }
 \hline
 \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\textbf{Crop field location info}} \\
 \hline
 \textbf{District name} & \textbf{Tehsil name} & \textbf{UC name} & \textbf{UC \#}\\
  & & &\\
 \hline
 \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\textbf{Farmer's info}} \\
 \hline
 \textbf{Farmer name} & \textbf{Farmer contact \#} & \multicolumn{2}{ |c| }{\textbf{Farmer's land holding (acres)}} \\
  & & \multicolumn{2}{ |c| }{} \\
 \hline
 \textbf{Item} & \textbf{Unit} & \textbf{Rate/Unit} & \textbf{Total Cost}\\
 \hline
\end{tabular}

Comment: I just noticed, that most of the table has five columns, so i think the best way to go is to use a tabular with initially five columns. I have updated my code example accordingly.