# can anyone help me this table in latex?

Tags: tables

[image: i tried to create code in latex for this table but i couldnt get for multi columns can anyone help me with this table]

```
 \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|}\hline
    Criterion & Discretization method & Dataset & Rank mean\\
    \hline
    \multirow{7}{*}{Cair mean value
     through all intervals} & Equal width \\
      & Equal frequency \\
     & Maximum entropy \\
     & IEM \\ 
     & CADD\\
     & CAIM\\
     \hline
     \multirow{7}{*}{Total no of intervals} & Equal width \\
      & Equal frequency \\
     & Maximum entropy \\
     & IEM \\ 
     & CADD\\
     & CAIM\\
     \hline
     \multirow{7}{*}{Time[s]} & Equal width \\
      & Equal frequency \\
     & Maximum entropy \\
     & IEM \\ 
     & CADD\\
     & CAIM\\
     \hline
```

here is the code that i tried  but  i dont understand how to write code from datasets  multiple columns can anyone please help me?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Unhelpful statement: This table looks awful and should **not** be reproduced at all (it's hard to read it)

Comment: can anyone help me how to write this table in latex

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Table with multirow and multicolumn](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/251648/table-with-multirow-and-multicolumn)

Comment: Make your table with 19 columns.  Then make the "Dataset" header span 16 of the columns using the \multicolumn command.

Answer (score 1):

This will do it. I've also used the `array` package to handle the varying font sizes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[centering,width=9.5in,height=7in]{geometry}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}
\geometry{landscape}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}

% Define column width as a command so it is easier to change
\newcommand{\ColIWidth}{.7in}

% p{\ColIWidth}      - column of specific width
% *{8}{...}          - Do "c|>{\footnotesize}c|" 8 times
% >{\footnotesize}c  - Centered column but prefix each with \footnotesize
\begin{tabular}{|p{\ColIWidth}|l|*{8}{c|>{\footnotesize}c|}c|}\hline
  % multirows and multicolumns where appropriate
  \multirow{2}{\ColIWidth}{\textbf{Criterion}} & \textbf{Discretization} & \multicolumn{16}{c|}{Dataset} & \textbf{RANK}\\\cline{3-18}
  & \textbf{method} & iris & std & sat & std & thy & std & wav & std & ion & std & smo & std & hea & std & pid & std & mean\\
  \hline
  % Need a width in the multirow in order to get desired wrapping.
  % The \vfil helps with vertical alignment.
  \multirow{7}{\ColIWidth}{CAIR mean value
   through all intervals\vfil} & Equal width & 0.40 & 0.01 & 0.24 & 0 \\
    & Equal frequency \\
   & Maximum entropy \\
   & IEM \\
   & CADD\\
   & CAIM\\
   \hline
   \multirow{7}{\ColIWidth}{Total no of intervals\vfil} & Equal width \\
    & Equal frequency \\
   & Maximum entropy \\
   & IEM \\
   & CADD\\
   & CAIM\\
   \hline
   \multirow{7}{\ColIWidth}{Time[s]\vfil} & Equal width \\
    & Equal frequency \\
   & Maximum entropy \\
   & IEM \\
   & CADD\\
   & CAIM\\
   \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image: Screenshot of The Table]

Comment: thankyou so much and can you please  close  all  the  lines

Comment: @user58954 The lines will close when the rows are full.